# Enforce that all inputs of some type `T` to methods of a trait `F` have been previously produced by `F` itself

Tags: scala, types, polymorphism, path-dependent-type, type-members

Suppose that I have some trait `Foo`, for example:

```
trait Foo {
  def bar: List[Int]
  def baz(i: Int): Unit
}
```

I want to enforce at compile time that all inputs passed to `baz` have been previously produced by `bar`. For example, if this is an implementation of `Foo`:

```
object A extends Foo {
  def bar = List(2, 3, 5, 7)
  def baz(i: Int): Unit = {
    if (bar contains i) println("ok")
    else println("not good")
  }
}
```

then I want to enforce that only single-digit primes can be passed to `baz`. This obviously doesn't work if the input type of `baz` is known to be `Int`, because it allows me to instantiate all kinds of integers that are not prime and not between `0` and `9`:

```
val okValues: List[Int] = A.bar
A.baz(okValues(1)) // ok
A.baz(3)           // ok (but dangerous! `3` appeared out of nowhere!)
A.baz(42)          // not good
```

How can I enforce that only the values previously produced by `bar` can be passed to `baz`?

---

**What doesn't work**

Converting `Int` to a type member of `Foo` doesn't help, because it's instantiated to the concrete type `Int` in the implementation `A` of `Foo`:

```
trait Foo {
  type T
  def bar: List[T]
  def baz(t: T): Unit
}

object A extends Foo {
  type T = Int 
  def bar = List(2, 3, 4, 5)
  def baz(i: Int): Unit = {
    if (bar contains i) println("ok")
    else println("not good")
  } 
}

A.baz(42) // not good
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution that relies on replacing a concrete type `Int` by an abstract type member `T`, and then simply not exposing the concrete implementation of `T` by `Int`:

- replace the concrete type `Int` by an abstract type member `T`
- move methods `bar` and `baz` and the type `T` into an inner trait `YFoo`
- inside `Foo`, provide a method that produces `YFoo`, but does not expose what `T` is.

In code:

```
trait Foo {
  trait YFoo {
    type T
    def bar: List[T]
    def baz(i: T): Unit
  }
  def yFoo: YFoo
}

object B extends Foo {
  def yFoo: YFoo = new YFoo {
    type T = Int
    def bar: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 5, 7)
    def baz(i: Int): Unit = {
      if (bar contains i) println("ok")
      else println("not good")
    }
  }
}

val a = B.yFoo
val okValues: List[a.T] = a.bar
a.baz(okValues(1)) // ok
// a.baz(3)           // dangerous stuff doesn't compile!
// found   : Int(3)
// required: a.T

// a.baz(42)          // invalid stuff also doesn't compile
// found   : Int(42)
// required: a.T
```

Now all the dangerous / invalid stuff doesn't even compile. The only values that you can pass to `baz` are those from the "list of certified values" produced by `bar`.

Comment: Any hints how to achieve this without all the noise caused by nested trait?